# Alert box once logged in that there's a new record inserted on a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on this employee management system and its leave system feature. 
Once an employee filed a request for leave, and when the admin logged in on the EMS, he will be alerted that theres a new request for leave.

Is that possible?

Comment: You may want to ask a more specific question to get help.  Of course it's *possible*.  Anything is possible...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's pretty simple. If an employee filled up a form and submitted it, the admin will be alerted that that employee filled up the form when he logs in.

Comment: Are you asking for the code to do this or what?  Create a database table with employee time-off requests and a "seen by manager" column that defaults to false and is set to true at manager log in

Comment: @ExplosionPills Im not asking for the code. Just the logic of it. Thanks, that's actually a good idea. So if a record is unseen, it will be alerted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After admin login you need to call ajax function to check if new leave entry is added or not.
Sample code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url         : 'server.php',
            dataType    : 'json',
            beforeSend  : function()
            {
                // show loading or else
            },
            success     : function(response)
            {
                if(response)
                {
                    // display it in right side div.
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
    //database connections

    $query = mysqli_query("select * from leave_table where status = 0")or die(mysqli_error());
    //status 0 to check if entry is previously seen or not. 
    $response = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $response = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
?>
```

And for checking new entry everytime then all you need to do is make ajax call as function and setInterval for calling that function for number of second as you want.

Take a look at [SetInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

And one more alternative is to use **COMET AJAX**.

feel free to ask.

Comment: You could also create an alert javascript function and then populate a call to that function from php when the page is generated. Just don't forget to wrap the function call in $(document).ready()

Comment: Right, I was just saying you didn't need to use ajax if you populated the function call for alert form php.